# Windows Python: how to get opened file path from within the associated file type handler program?

Tags: python, path, exe, file-type-associations

I am using Windows. I have files that are AES encrypted and saved with a certain file extension. What I want to do is to write a python program that I can use as the handler for that file type. In other words, when I double-click a file of that type, it should start my python program, which will then process the file. So far I have it to the point where my program runs in response to such a file being opened.

What I am stuck on is this: When I open a file that triggers my handler to run, how do I find the location of that file from within the handler program?

For example:

- `.abc` is associated to `C:\Program Files\my_file_handler.py`, so `my_file_handler.py` will run whenever I double-click a `.abc` file
- I double-click `C:\Users\my_stuff\cool_aes.abc`
- `C:\Program Files\my_file_handler.py` runs

within `my_file_handler.py`, how do i determine that `C:\Users\my_stuff\cool_aes.abc` was the file that triggered it to start? Is that information available in `sys` or `os` packages, or somewhere else?

Comment: my code is a exe somewhere on my pc and im clicking on the encrypted file to start the exe. Now i just need to get the path of the file that started the exe and use it, i think. I dont even know what exactly started the exe, some sort of "windows handler"?

Comment: Ok this seems like more of a windows quesion them. If you double click on a mp4 file, it opens the movie player you selected as default and plays that file. Ive got to the point where i double click my encrypted file and it opens my software. But now i need to get the file path from the file i clicked on, so the software can automatically select given file. But yeah i dont know exactly what starts the software, thats why im here

Comment: Oh, ok, you are looking for info on the mechanics of Windows file associations. It sounds like you have a file association defined that correctly associates a given file (or, more accurately a given **file type**) to your program, so that opening that file (file type) launches the program you associated to it. What you are trying to do is find out, from within the file handler (your program), the path of the file that lead to it being launched.  If that is right, you might want to edit the question to clarify it,  maybe using the description I just gave as a starting point.

Comment: I'm not a windows programmer, but you might want to see what is showing up in `sys.argv` and `os.environ`, they might have some clues... I can see why this might be hard to find info on, all I can find is instructions on how to assign `.py` files to python, but nothing that explains how to write a new file handler *in* python.